# Print device ID from xinput output in Linux matching a string

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, xinput

I am trying to write a script to automate the disabling/enabling my touchpad with `bash` script in `i3wm` but for that, I want to fetch the touchpad ID which is reported by the output of `xinput`. The idea of the script is to be easily transferrable between different machines, that is why I want to automate the extraction of the device ID of the touchpad.

```
$ xinput                                                                    
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL07BE:01 06CB:7A13 Mouse                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL07BE:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And I want a one-line command to give me the `id` of the `Touchpad`. I have tried with `awk` to implement it and the best which I achieved was to make

```
$ xinput | awk '/Touchpad/ && /id=/ { print $6 } '                          
id=15
```

The problem is that the 6th column is not every time the device ID so I need first to fetch the line containing `Touchpad` and then to print the numbers after `id=` and to cut at the first white space/tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` for the purpose:

```
xinput | sed '/Touchpad/s/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/;t;d'
```

This will replace the entire content of lines where the pattern `Touchpad` is found with the number in `id=digits` pattern via use of the capture group `\([0-9]*\)`, thereby effectively printing only the ID part, and ignore any non-matching lines (the `;t;d` part at the end).

Comment: I am actually needing to get `15` without the `id=` prefix.

Answer (score 3):

For `xinput`, commands which require a *device* argument (as in `--enable device`) can use the name or id of a device.

For example, both of these would be equivalent:

```
xinput --enable 'DLL07BE:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad'
```

```
xinput --enable 15
```

If you will not know the entire name of the device beforehand, use the output of `xinput --list --name-only` to find a matching name:

```
xinput --list --name-only | grep Touchpad
```

```
xinput --enable "$(xinput --list --name-only | grep Touchpad | head -n 1)"
```

As described in `man 1 xinput`, the `--list` option also accepts a device argument. So you could print the id given a name:

```
xinput --list --id-only 'DLL07BE:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad'
```

or a name given an id:

```
xinput --list --name-only 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below single awk command it will work fine

Tested and worked fine

```
xinput |awk '/Touchpad/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /id/){print $i}}}'
```

output

```
id=15
```